# Why does segmentation error occur when I run this? It works as a TCP client-server and the segmentation fault occurs at the userid input at the client

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, scanf, client-server

## server.c

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int sd,b,len,l,ad,port,i,flag=0;
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    char userid[100],id[3];
    char password[100],*line;
    size_t read,length=100;
        printf("Enter port number: ");
    scanf("%d",&port);
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    server.sin_family=AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port=htons(port);
    sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sd>0)
    {
        printf("\nSocket Creation Successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSocket creation failed!");
    }
    b=bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
    if(b>=0)
    {
      printf("\nBinding Successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nBinding Error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    l=listen(sd,1);
    if (l>=0)
    {
        printf("\nListening...");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nListening Failed!");
        exit(0);
    }
    len=sizeof(client);
    ad=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&client,&len);
    if(ad==0)
    {
        printf("\nAccepting error!");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
    printf("\nAccepting...");
    }
    send(sd,"220",100,0);
    recv(ad,userid,100,0);
    send(sd,"331",100,0);
        recv(ad,password,100,0);
    strcat(strcat(userid," "),password);
    fp1=fopen("database.txt","r");
    while((read=getline(&line,&length,fp1))!=-1)
    {
        if(strcmp(line,userid)==0)
        {
                flag=1;
                break;
                }
        }
        fclose(fp1);
        if(flag==1)
        {
                printf("User found!");
                send(sd,"230",100,0);
        }
        while(userid[i]!=' ')
        {
                id[i]=userid[i];
                i++;
        }
        fp2=fopen("studb.txt","r");
        if(id[0]=='s')
        {
                while((read=getline(&line,&length,fp2))!=-1)
                {
                        if(line[1]==userid[1]&&line[2]==userid[2])
                        {
                                send(sd,&line,sizeof(line),0);
                                break;
                        }
                }
                send(sd,"221",100,0);
        }
 if(id[0]=='f')
        {

                while((read=getline(&line,&length,fp2))!=-1)
                {
                        send(sd,&line,sizeof(line),0);
                }
                send(sd,"221",100,0);
        }
        close(sd);
        printf("Disconnected Successfully!");
        return 0;
}
```

## client.c

```
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int sd,b,l,len,ad,port;
    char userid[100];
    char *password,*code,*msg,*filename;
    printf("Enter the port number: ");
    scanf("%d",&port);
    struct sockaddr_in server,client;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    sd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(sd>0)
    {
        printf("\nSocket Creation Successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nSocket creation failed!");
    }
    l=connect(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&server,sizeof(server));
    if(l>=0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Successful!");
}
    else
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed!");
        exit(0);
    }
   recv(sd,&code,100,0);
   if(strcmp(code,"220")==0)
    {
        printf("Service Ready!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("FTP Server Not Ready!");
    exit(0);
    }
    printf("\nEnter userid: ");
    scanf("%s",&userid);
    printf("%s",userid);
    send(sd,userid,100,0);
    recv(sd,&code,100,0);
    if(strcmp(code,"331")==0)
    {
    password=getpass("Enter password: ");
    send(sd,password,sizeof(password),0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error!");
    exit(0);
    }
    recv(sd,&code,100,0);
    if(strcmp(code,"230")==0)
    {
        printf("\nLogin successful!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nInvalid credentials!");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Enter filename: ");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    send(sd,filename,sizeof(filename),0);
    recv(sd,&code,100,0);
    if(strcmp(code,"150")==0)
    {
        printf("\nData Connection Successful! \nRetreiving records for the user...");
    }
    do
    {
            recv(sd,&msg,sizeof(msg),0);
            puts(msg);
            printf("\n");
    }while(strcmp(msg,"226")!=0);
    close(sd);
    printf("\nDisconnected Successfully!");
    return 0;
}
```

> Pardon for the inefficiency of code : (

When I run the client and server paralelly, I could infer that the client and server are getting connected, but no info is transferred due to the segmentation fault that occurs at the client side. I'm a pure beginner & could not figure out what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `send(sd,"221",100,0);` is invalid. `"221"` only has 4 bytes (3 characters and the null terminator). You're reading outside the array. It should be `send(sd,"221",sizeof("221"),0);`

Comment: you're not allocating any memory for `code`

Comment: `sizeof(password)` is not correct. `password` is a pointer, `sizeof` is not the length of the string it points to. Use `strlen(password)+1`

Comment: You're also not allocating memory for `msg`. After you allocate memory, you should use `recv(sd, msg, space_allocated, 0);`

Comment: The usual. As the other comments above, mishandling of TCP octet streams by assuming 'messages' of more than one byte, failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls like recv(), failure to ensure that 'string' calls like 'strcmp' are called with NUL-terminated char arrays.